# How to add an image to ListView column header?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

It should be easy, right?
Have a listview, add an imagelist, add images to the imagelist, assign image index to the column you want.
But, it doesn't work.
[Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314933) states that it is a known problem in .NET 1.1.
But has it been fixed since?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to use Interop. I suggest you to use the example given in the article.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do. One would think this issues could have been solved already.

Comment: Alas, one can barely do anything advanced with Window Forms without resorting to WinAPI…

Answer (score 1):

I did like this
1)made imagelist1

2)set the listviewlarge=imagelist1 & samallImagelist = imagelist1

3)write to form initilaize area
this.Columname0.ImageIndex = 0;
this.Columname1.ImageIndex = 1;

its work.